# Relationship of BigQuery to other kind of database

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore

I am asked to move huge data from BigQuery to Firestore. However, after searching on the Internet, I realised that there is rarely a discussion about moving data from BigQuery to any other database. From the search results, most of them is about moving data from any source into BigQuery. Even in Dataflow Google Templates, there are only xxx to BigQuery templates but no BigQuery to xxx pipeline found.

From the reason I get, is to tackle the example such as, after we get a lot of data from Google Analytic to BigQuery, we performs joins and some filtering to come out with some useful insights, which can be served to client later. To serve the result quickly, instead of BigQuery, we move the data to Firestore so it can perform read faster for large amount of users. Is this right approach?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, your best bet is probably just [exporting your data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) into file in Cloud Storage and then [importing that file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) to Cloud Firestore.

The whole process can be scripted, so it’s possible to automate it and schedule it according to your needs.

Comment: Hmm how about BigQuery to Firestore through DataFlow? Sadly there is no FirestoreIO support at this moment. And it is kind of slow when I implemented the Firestore Write. Not sure its the problem of reinitialize firestore app every time the runner try to write data into Firestore. I could not pass the credential reference into the pipeline, due to the fact that it cannot be pickled. I got another suggestion which is BigQuery -> Pub/Sub through Dataflow, and Pub/Sub will go through App Engine/Cloud Function to write into Firestore. Stucked on the stream / batch mode on Bq and Pub/Sub.

Comment: That's why I didn't suggest DataFlow, because there is no official FirestoreIO provided at this point... The Pub/Sub+Cloud Functions workaround is nice if you have many inputs in streaming, but since in your case you need to move a lot of data at once, I think it would be very inefficient.
If you want to try and implement your own FirestoreIO, here are some good practices you can follow: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-custom-io/